# Access control while developing framework for third party

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

My team is developing a ios framework for third party companies using swift. In order to adapt swift pattern, we decided to using simple naming class and encapsulate them into several modules (in this case, frameworks).However, these frameworks are all accessed by third parties which is not I expect

My question is how to prevent it or is there anything we did wrongly?

For example, my Module(framework) A, is what I want to expose to third party, but A have A dependency over module(framework) B, But I do not want third part to see B.

FYI, make B static is not the correct way because third party can still import B after linking A.

Comment: The 'Internal' keyword should do what you need, docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, but 'Internal' makes the resource visible anywhere inside the module and invisible anywhere out side. It is not useful to module level. my goal is to make some modules only visible to some designated modules. @GoatInTheMachine